# Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7 -- Using a USB-C Dock with Display Link and external monitors -- Only 1 monitor has the scaled option 1600 x 900

Tags: display, dock, displayport, resolution

I have a Macbook pro (Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7) which I'm connecting to a docking station via a USBC. I have 2 external monitors 1 connected to the dock via HDMI, 1 via DP.

When I go to `Settings --> Displays --> Display Tab --> Scaled` only the monitor connected via HDMI has the `1600 x 900` option. I've tried clicking scaled while holding down alt and I do see other options but not `1600 x 900` which I find to be optimal.

Please let me know if I can provide other helpful info.
My hunch is that because both monitors are technically only connected to one usbc on the laptop, there is some weird issue.

Edit:

- Both monitors are the exact same model: [Samsung S24R356FHN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084KTZP7N)
- The dock is a [Totu](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0838WTFD1)
- Macbook pro model: a2141

Comment: What make/model is each monitor? What's their native resolutions? Often, rescale options are in simple arithmetical divisors of the native.

Comment: **...and** the make and model of docking station too. Add it all to your original question *not a comment*

Comment: Which model **MacBook Pro** do you have?